# WinSCP on SFTP Changes Owner When Editing Files

Tags: sftp, winscp

WinSCP on SFTP changes file ownership when editing files. How to prohibit changing the owner when editing a file?

Comment: Can you please add more information? How does it change owners? Did you try to copy using WinSCP?

Comment: Your question is off-topic on Stack Overflow. It would be on-topic on [su]. But it's already answered there: [WinSCP keeps changing file owner](https://superuser.com/q/1323408/213663).